# Gsuite directory_v1 api for user creation getting error 403

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-client, google-workspace, google-directory-api

I've created a `serviceaccount` in json with `enabled domain-wide delegation` also `Authorize` the `SCOPS` in the below code:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from google.oauth2 import service_account

scopes=[
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly',
        ]
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'servie_account_file.json'

# The user we want to "impersonate"
USER_EMAIL = "superadmin@domain.com"

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=scopes)
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject(USER_EMAIL)
service = discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
response = service.users().list(domain='domain.com').execute()
print(response)
```

but getting the error `403` response

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=domain.com&alt=json returned "Not Authorized to access this resource/api">
```

[link](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Backup/How_to_obtain_authorization_from_Google_for_using_Active_Backup_for_G_Suite) I've used for authorization.

Comment: I want to use this code like cron.

Comment: What roles did you assign to the service account in the IAM console? Scopes do not add roles, they limit permissions from assigned roles. Just use the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` and control permissions via the roles assigned to the service account.

Comment: Given owner access to the service account.

Comment: Did you implement the rest of my comment?

Comment: FYI: The title of your question does not match your code. Spend some time getting everything written correctly.